# nginx config to load angular6 app as module of main app

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I need all requests to app.com/blah/* to be handled by an angular6 app, but all other requests to app.com/* to be handled by tomcat. I was to add a module to an already existing application.

The problem with below config is: location / overrides the entire config and causes all requests to be handled by tomcat.

See config below

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name staging.app.com;
root /las/blah/app;
client_max_body_size 980M;
include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

   location ^~ /blah/ {
           try_files $uri /index.html;
   }

    location / {
           proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
           proxy_set_header Host $host;
           proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
           proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
           proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
   }

error_page 404 /404.html;
       location = /40x.html {
   }

error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
       location = /50x.html {
   }
```

}

Please Help

Comment: Where is `/index.html`? At the moment it is fetched from tomcat. Either place it under `/blah` or add a specific location for it.

Comment: @RichardSmith, it's unclear what you're suggesting.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved it.

```
location ^~ /blah {
       alias   /las/blah/app;
       try_files $uri /blah/index.html;
    }
```

The key is alias.